# How to keep data structures and XML file in sync

Tags: android, xml, data-structures

I am writing an app with data structures of lists and sub lists and items.

I would like to save (`onPause`) and restore (`onCreate`) this data from/to XML files - so later on I will be able to send and share it.
The user can manipulate the data structures (add, remove, update, etc.).

My question is: what is the best approach for keeping the XML and the data structures coherent?

Comment: imho, json would be much easier

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach for this type of problem (in general, not just on Android) is to store the data locally in the manner that is most efficient and reliable for update and retrieval, and to generate interchange formats (such as xml, json, etc.) when needed from the stored stored data.

On Android (and in most, if not all other environments), xml is a poor choice for local storage because it's relatively difficult to update efficiently (e.g. when anything changes, the entire xml file typically needs to be re-written).

For Android, you would typically store your "data structures" in a local database (SQLite by default) whenever the data is changed in memory. When you want to share that data, you would generate your interchange format from the data in the database. XML is certainly possible, but JSON is more typical.